# C Compiler Dependencies on the Architecture

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction, dependencies

When a C Program is compiled and and executable is created, The exe makes certain assumptions with respect to the compiler. For example when a c program is compiled on a 32 bit system and run on the 64 bit system, what are the attributes that a program will have that won't change with the architecture?

Comment: what I need to know is that what does a c compiled program do when it is compiled and what are the things that are binded with that program and architecture?

Comment: I just googled "C compiler design" and many interesting results came up. Why not do the same?

Comment: I did the same, but the dependencies I'm looking for are nowhere to be found, I posted my question here as a last resort. anyways i appreciate the help.

Comment: @user2857829 : Be specific about question.What dependencies are you looking exactly.

Comment: I've edited the question please re-read it.  It may be clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C compilers translate C code to machine code. Machine code is different for different types of CPUs. The number of registers, the word size and memory bus size also varies between different architectures.

Also, the interaction with the operating system is not the same. In an embedded system there might not even be any operating system.